# sql - How to return NULL row from left table for each parent even when child records exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, left-join

I have 2 tables with a parent-child relation.  I'd like to return a row with `NULL` child values for parents that have children, in addition to the child records.
For example, for tables parent and child:

```
SELECT parent.parentid, childid 
FROM parent    
LEFT JOIN child 
ON parent.parentid=child.parentid
```

For a parent `parentA` with children `childA1`, `childA2`, I'd like a result:

```
parentA, NULL
parentA, childA1
parentA, childA2
```

A normal LEFT JOIN will not return the first row.  A UNION query works, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler/better query, using standard SQL for Oracle and SQL Server.  My UNION query is:

```
SELECT parent.parentid, childid
FROM parent
INNER JOIN child ON parent.parentid=child.parentid

UNION

SELECT parent.parentid, NULL
FROM parent
```

Comment: The union is the way to do this.  Use UNION ALL so it doesn't need to try to dedupe the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is better written as:

```
SELECT p.parentid, childid
FROM parent p INNER JOIN
     child c
     ON p.parentid = c.parentid
UNION ALL
SELECT p.parentid, NULL
FROM parent p;
```

That is `UNION ALL` is better than `UNION`, because `UNION` has additional overhead for removing duplicate values.  If you can have duplicates in `parent`, just use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the second query.

Also, you might want to add an `ORDER BY` to get results in order the question seems to specify:

```
ORDER BY parentid, (CASE WHEN child is NULL then 0 else 1 end), chile
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing it would be

```
SELECT parent.parentid,
       childid
FROM   parent
       LEFT JOIN child
         ON parent.parentid = child.parentid
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS( ( parent.parentid ), ( parent.parentid, childid ) )
HAVING (childid IS NOT NULL) OR  GROUPING(childid) =1
ORDER  BY parentid ASC,
          GROUPING(childid) DESC
```

If you only want the row for parents with children you should use an inner join

- [SQL Fiddle - Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11586e/3)
- [SQL Fiddle - SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47ccb/1)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't familiar with grouping sets.  However, the query returns two identical records for parents without children:
[ParentB, NULL], [ParentB, NULL]